# How to create composable Keras layers while maintaining access to child layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create a custom Keras Layer that is composed of a variable number of other Keras layers. I want access to both the grouped layers treated as a single layer with an input and output as well as access to the individual sublayers.

I'm just wondering, **what is the "proper" method for performing this form of layer abstraction in Keras?**

I'm not sure if this should be done through Keras's Layer API, or if I can work with name scopes and wrapping layers in a function and then select all layers under some name scope. (e.g. `model.get_layer('custom1/*')`, but I don't think that works, and name_scope doesn't appear to apply to layer names)

One of the other issues with using Keras Layers for this is that you need to assign the child variables as direct attributes (I assume it makes use of the descriptor API) to the class in order for the trainable weights to be added to the model (which is messier when we don't have a fixed number of layers, meaning we'd need to hack something together with `setattr()`, which, ew).

Btw, this isn't my actual code, but is a barebones simplification of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```py
class CustomLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, *a, n_layers=2, **kw):
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        super().__init__(*a, **kw)

    def call(self, x):
        for i in range(self.n_layers):
            x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
            x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
        return x

input_shape, n_classes = (None, 100), 10
x = input = Input(input_shape)
x = CustomLayer()(x)
x = CustomLayer()(x)
x = Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model([input], [x])

'''

So this works fine

'''

print([l.name for l in model.layers])
print(model.layers[1].name)
print(model.layers[1].output)

# Output: ['input', 'custom_1', 'custom_2', 'dense']
# Output: 'custom_1'
# Output: the custom_1 output tensor

'''

But I'm not sure how to do something to the effect of this ...

'''

print(model.layers[1].layers[0].name)
print(model.layers[1].layers[0].output)

# Output: custom_1/dense
# Output: custom_1/dense output tensor
```